# Git reset does not revert files added and then removed

Tags: git, github, reset

When I was pushing my comit to master, I saw this:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 9e66701c691af788607f53b193b6cfe1
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File mongodb/journal/prealloc.2 is 424.62 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Then I removed all the directory `mongo`, but the error is still the same.

I tried to `git reset --hard` and more commands like I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540862/git-reset-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306821/why-wont-git-reset-head-undo-my-uncommitted-unstaged-changes) but didn't solve the error

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it was while uploading a new repository.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

When I do a `git reset --hard` the directory `mongo` appears again.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove the directory completely, go back to previous commit or something else?

Comment: *When I do a git reset --hard the directory mongo appears again.* that's normal. Are you aware of what a hard reset does?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I want to upload all the files to my GitHub repo. when I first did it the `mongo` directory was present and there was no way to remove it.

Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After some trials and error, I decided to `apt-get --purge remove git`, then I removed the `~/.git` directory. Now it pushes all files inside the directory without the `mongo` directory, because I have deleted it.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Of course, I have reinstalled git! And it solved all. Doesn't know why they fried me in downvotes... Because that is the solution! I read all about the 3 posts I linked and no one had the answer to my problem... And I discovered the answer by myself! The next user who has the same problem will know what to do... Really easy in comparison of reading 3 entire posts and don't finding the answer!

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. You uninstalled Git and deleted `.git/` from the directory, then pushed? Now (a) your directory is no longer a Git repository (so you _have nothing_ to push), and (b) you have no `git` program (so you can't run `git push`).

Comment: Scratch install is a solution to any problem. But at what cost?